# Hyperledger Facric CA: Override Certificate Signing Request (CSR) section by ENV

Tags: environment-variables, yaml, hyperledger, viper

I want to overrride this section of the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file by variables env:

```
csr:
  cn: fabric-ca-server
  names:
    - C: US
     ST: "North Carolina"
      L:
      O: Hyperledger
     OU: Fabric
  hosts:
    - host1.example.com
    - localhost
ca:
  expiry: 131400h
  pathlength: 1
```

For example I know that:

`FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=fabric-ca-server` is equivalent to csr.cn
but
csr.names??
csr.host??

Could it be?:

```
FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_NAMES=C:US,ST:"North Carolina",L:,O:Hyperledger,OU:Fabric
```

Regards

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it gave an error like: expected map, it got string... I have gave up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You can't override the CSR with env. variables, but you can customize the CSR in the config file.

---

**Long answer:**

There are two issues going on here:

1) The error you are getting states that the configuration is looking for a map (which is how it is formatted in the `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` file).

To create a map in a bash script variable, you need to declare the associative array:

```
declare -A FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_NAMES=( \
    [C]="US" \
    [ST]="Texas" \
    [L]="" \
    [O]="TangoJLabs" \
    [OU]="testenvvar" \
)
export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_NAMES
echo ${FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_NAMES[OU]}
```

2) However, environment variables [can only be strings](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3726#issuecomment-232166647), so it does not appear possible to override the configuration CSR settings with environment variables.  Something like `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_NAMES_OU` will not work because `names:` is a map, so there could be multiple `OU` entries.

The [docs state](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#initializing-the-server):

> If custom values for the CSR are required, you may customize the
>   configuration file, delete the files specified by the ca.certfile and
>   ca.keyfile configuration items, and then run the fabric-ca-server init
>   -b admin:adminpw command again.

So, what I typically do is just create a minimal config file and copy it over to the CA container before running `init`.  This seems to be enough (with the other sections taking default values):

```
registry:
  maxenrollments: -1
  identities:
     - name: mycompany-admin-ca
       pass: adminpw
       type: client
       affiliation: ""
       attrs:
          hf.Registrar.Roles: "*"
          hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles: "*"
          hf.Revoker: true
          hf.IntermediateCA: true
          hf.GenCRL: true
          hf.Registrar.Attributes: "*"
          hf.AffiliationMgr: true

affiliations:
  mycompany: []

csr:
   cn: mycompany-ca
   names:
      - C: US
        ST: Texas
        L:
        O: MyCompany
        OU: client
   hosts:
     - mycompany-ca
   ca:
      expiry: 131400h
      pathlength: 1
```

For some reason, if you include a custom `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` file but exclude the `registry:` section, it does not register a bootstrap user, even if you use the command line `-b` option.  So, if you include that `registry:` section, you therefore don't need the `-b` option when you run `init`.

You might also want to include the `ca:` section since you can force the created certificate to be saved to your custom name:

```
ca:
  name: mycompany-ca
  keyfile: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/mycompany-ca-cert.key
  certfile: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/mycompany-ca-cert.pem
  chainfile:
```

Also, before running `init` I would clean up your home directory - sometimes the default `ca-cert.pem` (and key) already exist and are not replaced:

```
rm $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/ca-cert.pem
rm -R $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/msp
```

Of course, after running `init` your key will be saved in the `msp` directory tree under:

```
msp
    └── keystore
        ├── {...}_sk
```

I typically move it to the home directory and rename it for convenience:

```
cp $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/msp/keystore/*_sk $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/mycompany-ca-cert.key
```